# Custom icon font not loaded

Tags: css, svg, sass, gulp, icon-fonts

Using gulp-iconfont-css, I'm trying to compile Material Design svg into a font. This is the part of my Gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('iconfont', function(){
  gulp.src(paths.svg)
    .pipe(iconfontCss({
      fontName: 'material-design', // required
      path: './www/sass/templates/_icons.scss',
      targetPath: '../sass/_icons.scss',
      fontPath: '/fonts/'
    })).pipe(iconfont({
      fontName: 'material-design', // required
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/fonts/'));
});
```

And now my template:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "<%= fontName %>";
    src: url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.eot');
    src: url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
        url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.woff') format('woff'),
        url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.svg#<%= fontName %>') format('svg');
}

.icon:before {
    font-family: "<%= fontName %>";
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    // speak: none; // only necessary if not using the private unicode range (firstGlyph option)
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

<% _.each(glyphs, function(glyph) { %>
<% var array = glyph.fileName.split('_') %>
.icon-<%= array.slice(1, array.length - 1).join('-') %>:before {
    content: "\<%= glyph.codePoint %>";
}
<% }); %>
```

Problem: **My icons are not loaded** When I create an element like this:

```
 <i class="icon-send"></i>
```

I see nothing. And the font is never downloaded on the server (in the network log). Also, **the icons are defined two times with different values**. Extract:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "material-design";
  src: url('/fonts/material-design.eot');
  src: url('/fonts/material-design.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('/fonts/material-design.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/material-design.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/material-design.svg#material-design') format('svg'); }

.icon:before {
  font-family: "material-design";
  ...
  text-transform: none; }

.icon-3d-rotation:before {
  content: "\E001"; }

.icon-3d-rotation:before {
  content: "\E002"; }

.icon-accessibility:before {
  content: "\E003"; }

.icon-accessibility:before {
  content: "\E004"; }
```

Comment: Did you verify that the path to the font is correct?  Or that the generated CSS is valid?

Comment: This is the generated css file https://gist.github.com/vinz243/7f793f97d359bc8e4152 There is no 404 or any request to any font (except roboto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it perhaps because the font is not set?  The font-family is defined in the "icon" class, but you are not specifying that.  What happens if you use the following instead?

```
<i class="icon icon-send"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks that was the solution it seemed. I had posted the answer but someone had removed it:/

Comment: I removed in error ._. I'll still accept your post;)

Comment: And the problem of several times the same icon was due to the fact that the  icons where several times in material-design-icons with different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two classes to have your icon working, you could change your font-family to be added on all the CSS classes that begin with `icon-`.

Then you will only have to do something like this:

```
<i class="icon-send"></i>
```

Here is the change to make:

```
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "material-design";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to apply the class `icon` ._.

```
 <i class="icon icon-reply"></i>
```