# Why custom font-icons are not loading on first load?

Tags: css, svg, fonts, gulp, loading

I have converted material svg as font icons in my project using GULP, similar to [custom icon fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443105/). Occasionaly, these font-icons are appearing jumbled/empty and on refresh, all icons are arranged properly in the site.

Example: [instagram icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpiw8.png) instead of [apple icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UstyJ.png)

This happens occasionally and only in published site, why is it happening like this and how to solve this?

Note: After adding text-rendering:optimizeLegibility; in font css , this issue started.

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand a bit the problem: are you seeing no icons? Are you seeing a [FOIT](https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/)?

Comment: when the page loads for the first time, All the icons are misplaced or empty. for example, the Apple icon is replaced with instagram icon, arrow icon is empty.

Comment: Are you including multiple font icons definition in the page?

Comment: We are using two custom font icons definition.

Comment: I suspect that what you see on first load is the page rendered without the fonts assets or with the fonts partially loaded. Have a try using a WebFontLoader to load the fonts.